# Use tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, metrics

I am trying to find a way of using `tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy` as Keras metric.

My classes are binary and the metric I want to perform is :
[this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkJoI.jpg). So it perfectly corresponds to `mean_per_class accuracy` from TF.

I could actually code it but I don't master tensorflow tensors

`binary_accuracy` and `categorical_accuracy`in keras do not precisely perform the metric I want.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below function:

```py
def mean_per_class_acc(y_true, y_pred):
    score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(y_true, y_pred, num_classes=4)
    K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
    with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
        score = tf.identity(score)       
    return score
```

Use it in your model as:

```
model.compile(loss= loss, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[mean_per_class_acc])
```